# Transform one-dimensional Numpy array into mask suitable for array index update of 2-dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

Given a 2-dimensional array a, I want to update select indices specified by b to a fixed value of 1.

test data:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array(
    [[0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]]
)

b = np.array([1, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3])
```

One solution is to transform b into a masked array like this:

```
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

which would allow me to do `a[b.astype(bool)] = 1` and solve the problem.

How can I transform b into the "mask" version below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to build the mask, use indexing directly:

```
a[np.arange(len(b)), b] = 1
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

That said, the mask could be built using:

```
mask = b[:,None] == np.arange(a.shape[1])
```

Output:

```
array([[False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True]])
```

Comment: Ah I see, this is what I tried doing with `a[:,b]` but did not work as I expected

Comment: note that without clearing `a`, (4,1) is still set to 1, though it's not in the example result!

Comment: @ti7 it was already set to 1, the first operation only changes the assigned indices, If you need to build an array with only the 1s and all 0s for the rest use the `mask` ;)

Comment: indeed / just so!

Comment: For my actual use case I needed to update only a subset of "a" - so went with your mask solution above which I was able to modify - worked fantastic

Answer (score 0):

A (probably worse) alternate method would be to compute the offsets for the unraveled array and use [`unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html), though this might be practical if you had more than 2 dimensions or to make some sparse matrix

```py
>>> idx = b + np.arange(len(b))*a.shape[-1]
>>> idx
array([ 1,  6, 10, 12, 19, 23])
>>> idx_multi = np.unravel_index(idx, a.shape)
>>> idx_multi
(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([1, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3]))
>>> a[:] = 0  # clear a
>>> a[idx_multi] = 1
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```